# SharePoint 2010 upgraded to 2013 blog category not work

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, blog, filter, categories

After checking all answers about SharePoint 2013 blog problems& I found that My problem is new. it is about 1 month that we upgraded from SharePoint 2010 to 2013. The problem is that when we click on categories on left panel is shows all items and the filter is not working.
I've tried the instructions regarding adding blog tool on Category.aspx? and Post.aspx? but they both had one. I don't know what to do and I cannot re create all blogs with hundreds of items!
I appreciate of some one help me or share the experiance

Answer (score 0):

Please look this site http://blog.hametbenoit.info/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=584 (not my :), but I have that issue too.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Since I searched and didn't find the main answer I made another blog and copied the content from Content and Structure. it worked but new solution is new experience! Surly I will check the codes and solution.